# i want to send a file in discord channel and the bot will read this file

Tags: javascript, file, discord, discord.js, attachment

im a developer of discord bots.
and i want to know how i can make the bot read a file that i send in a discord server
for example:

```
!read (file)
```

and the bot will log the content of the file or will send it like

```
message.channel.send(content)
```

i tried few stuff and they doesnt work..

here is code i tried:

```html
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const fs = require("fs")
module.exports.run = async(client, message, args, item) => {
 if(!message.member.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR')) return

      let useTips = new Discord.RichEmbed();
                useTips.setAuthor(message.author.tag, message.author.avatarURL)
                useTips.setDescription('Please Send A File')
                useTips.setColor(0xdb001d)
      message.channel.send(useTips)
      const filter = m => m.author.id === message.author.id;
      await message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, {max: 1, time: 30000,errors: ['time']})
                .then(collected => {
                        let collection = collected.first();
                        let file21 = collection.attachments;
                        message.channel.send(file21)
                          fs.readFile(file21, (err, data) => {
                          message.channel.send(data);
  });
                       
                })
              
                
}
```

but it didnt work..
someone can help me please?

Comment: What does "it didn't work" mean?

Comment: its just not work.. i dont know why but its not sending the content/data of the file im sending, so i need help with that

Comment: You need to be specific, "it just doesn't work" is not a description of your issue. Which part does not work, reading the file or sending the message or which step in the whole process exactly?

Comment: i dont know, its not sending the content/data of the file im sending in the channel, and i dont even know if its store the file that i send or even read it. so i need help, so if you can take the code and see what wrong and than fix it than it will ba amazing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can`t read attachment as file. You need get this attachment from url. 
The 1 way its use node request libary

```
    const Discord = require("discord.js");
    const fs = require("fs")
    const request = require('request');
    module.exports.run = async(client, message, args, item) => {
     if(!message.member.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR')) return

          let useTips = new Discord.RichEmbed();
                    useTips.setAuthor(message.author.tag, message.author.avatarURL)
                    useTips.setDescription('Please Send A File')
                    useTips.setColor(0xdb001d)
          message.channel.send(useTips)
          const filter = m => m.author.id === message.author.id;
          await message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, {max: 1, time: 30000,errors: ['time']})
                    .then(collected => {
                            let collection = collected.first();
                            if(!collection.attachments) return
                            request.get(collection.attachments.array()[0].url, function (error, response, body) {
                            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                              console.log(body)
                                }
                            });

                    })
                    .catch(console.error)
    }
}
```

Comment: its not working.. there is no error, its just not working, i send the file after it told me to send file but it didnt send the content of the file, i did "message.channel.send(data)" but it didnt send anything

Comment: console log data pls. Whats its return? 
And what filetype you are send?

Comment: i send txt file type, its not return noting when i console log data, there is just noting on the console

Comment: please someone? its 911... i need it now

Comment: i`ll self test it again and answer you today

Comment: I`m so sorry, i fix it. Forgot the discord attachment its collection too, so url of collection was undefined

Comment: I edit my answer, its works now. 
`console.log(body)`
will display file content in console.
You can use `message.channel.send(body)` to send this content. But discord max message length its 2000